# Passing VM parameter in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

My program only works with ip4 and gives an error with ip6 so I need to run the jar with

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Is there a way to write this line into pom.xml and whenever someone opens the jar that the application will try to connect IPv4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that at build time. The parameter is passed to the JVM when `java -jar artifact.jar` is run.

Your alternative is to do that yourself in code (main method is probably the place where you can change this property the earliest possible):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
}
```

Comment: Will this also work in another non-developer computer when I built the jar?

Comment: Yes, as this is in your code, it will work anywhere, as long as you don't have alternative main classes for users to choose from when launching your jar

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maven-surefire-plugin` :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>

            <java.net.preferIPv4Stack>true</java.net.preferIPv4Stack>

          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

More details in this [link](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).

Comment: Will this also work with build time? Or only in jar? And will this also work in another non-developer computer when I built the jar?

Comment: it's into <build> , i think it's works with build time, but i'm not sure